# wifiのパスワードを複数設定する方法

Tags: wifi

複数の子機androidと一台の親機androidをwifiをつなぐとします。
それぞれのandroidはそれぞれの別こパスワードを使って、wifiを接続します。
親機androidから、子機androidのwifi接続を切断パスワードを閉じ、以後接続できないようにする。
このようにすることは可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

ご質問のようなケースでは、パスワードではどうしても限界があるので、以下の記事で3回に渡って連載されている内容を読むとわかりますが、WPA2エンタープライズ認証をおすすめします。IDとパスワードによるユーザ別認証と、電子証明書を使った認証方式が使えます。

https://news.mynavi.jp/kikaku/wlan-auth-1/

https://news.mynavi.jp/kikaku/wlan-auth-2/